# Travelling with tissue samples in RNAlater

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques, rna

I've been in Brazil collecting some samples (ants) and need to travel back to to the UK with - I've got their brains stored in RNAlater, which have been in the freezer at -4C for a bit less than a month. On the Fisher Scientific website it says that they can be left at 37C for a day in solution before the RNA can begin to degrade. I've got a long journey home which could take up to 3 days in the heat (it's around 38C at the moment here) and involves stopping off through Morocco.

Has anyone travelled with samples in RNAlater like this before in elevated temperatures and got good results from their RNA extractions? Would you reccomend trying to source some dry ice for the journey?

Comment: Though I have not really tried it, I think that keeping the suspended tissues at 37⁰C for three days is not a good idea. You can try getting some ice from local shops and keep the samples in ice inside a thermocol box. IMO, the best option would be to courier your samples from Brazil to UK.